# Is Oracle ORDER BY sorting stable?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Oracle version is `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production`
Inserted 10000 records with the same name value, then order by name, pageSize is 1000 and eventually could get 10000 id successfully. So it seems the sort is stable.

Insert sql:

```
@Insert("insert into org_info(isvalid, update_time, org_uni_code,ORG_CHI_NAME) values(#{isvalid}, TO_TIMESTAMP(#{updateTimeStr}, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'), #{orgUniCode},#{name})")
void insertOrgInfo(int isvalid, String updateTimeStr, Long orgUniCode, String name);
```

Query sql:

```
@Select("select org_uni_code from (" +
        " select org_uni_code, rownum rn from(" +
        " select org_uni_code from org_info where update_time >= TO_TIMESTAMP(#{updateTimeStr}, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff') order by ORG_CHI_NAME" +
        " )" +
        " ) where rn > #{start} and rn<=#{end}")
List<Long> pagingGetOrgUniCodeList(String updateTimeStr, int start, int end);
```

Comment: Show us the SQL for the insert and query.

Comment: @StephenC Have added the insert and query sql

Comment: `ROWNUM` is an Oracle specific feature, a "pseudo column" that is applied to the resultset before sorting. If you must rely on a sort in a derived table (subquery) I suggest you use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...)` instead

Answer (score 1):

Oracle database sorting is not stable; the way data is inserted does not have a guaranteed relationship to the way data is returned.

(Note that [sort stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) means that the original order is preserved *when there are ties in the requested sort order*.  Asking if Oracle has a stable sort is slightly different than asking the more common question "will Oracle return rows in the order inserted?")

There are many times when Oracle sorts *look* stable, but it's easy to build test cases that demonstrate unstable sorting.  If we want guaranteed sort behavior we must fully specify the expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause.

For example, the trivial test case below inserted values for the `B` column in order 1, 2, 3.  But when sorting by `A`, it returned the `B` values in order 1,3,2.

```
--drop table table1;
create table table1(a number, b number);
insert into table1 select 1,1 from dual;
insert into table1 select 1,2 from dual;
insert into table1 select 1,3 from dual;

select * from table1 order by a;

A   B
-   -
1   1
1   3
1   2
```

The exact algorithms are not documented so this behavior may not be easily reproducible.  But if you play around with sorting enough, you will easily find examples of unstable sorting.

Comment: I am more than sure this scenario is not only limited to Oracle. SQL tables represents unordered sets. Your result is absolutely stable as column `a` perfectly sorted. Sorting in SQL tables is only stable if you have a deterministic order by clause.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I updated my answer with an explanation of what stable sorting means.  I hadn't heard of that phrase before, but I believe that my test case is an example of non-stable sorting.  Yes, Oracle sorted perfectly by `A`, but it didn't preserve the actual order of rows.  (Because, as you point out, SQL tables are unordered sets.)

Comment: @JonHeller In my case I do not care if return rows in the order inserted? I just want return all rows  and without duplicate, e.g  Inserted 100 user records, and all these user records have the same name ,  then paging query order by name pageSIze is 10 I just want every page have different user id is ok if satisfy this requirements for me it's stable. If one same record e.g, 1 john appeared in several pages , it's unstable

Comment: @zhuguowei Looks like I misunderstood your question.  If you want to avoid duplicates, can you simply change the innermost `select org_uni_code` to `select distinct org_uni_code`?